# How to add my native service to the existing group in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm creating a native service with C/C++ in Android.
This service will be responsible for custom video encoding/decoding manipulation.

The device nodes which are responsible for video encoding/decoding are as described as below in ueventd.xxx.rc and in file_contexts for sepolicy.

**ueventd.xxx.rc**

- /dev/vendor-encoder    0660   media  camera
- /dev/vendor-decoder    0660   media  camera

**sepolicy/file_contexts**

- /dev/vendor-encoder    u:object_r:camera_device:s0
- /dev/vendor-decoder    u:object_r:camera_device:s0

I'd like to make my own native service access these nodes so I think my service should be added to media group.

Could you let me know how to do this?

In case of Android service, it can be done by using sharedUsrId in AndroidManifest.xml. For example,
   android:sharedUserId="android.uid.media"

Thanks